# What are the specific interactions between a Wallet client/node and a Miner?

Tags: wallet, protocol, mining-theory, terminology

I'm researching the interactions between a Wallet and a Miner.  Although I'm also interested in the high level sequence of operations, I'm also interested in discovering the protocol and verbs used in the TCP connection.

> What are the specific interactions between a Wallet client/node and a Miner?

Comment: Are you talking about transaction creation, and it subsequently being mined into a block; or about mining payouts?

Comment: @PieterWuille I now see how this can be broken into two questions.  I assume most newcomers will not be aware of this distinction and may appreciate seeing the differences side by side (or above and below in SE).  Do you think I should edit this and ask two independent questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wallet is used by a client to store Bitcoin Addresses. The standard client can be ran in a server mode, which will allow it to take HTTP JSON RPC commands. One of them is "getwork" - a standard command used by miners to get data to hash. The standard client creates new blocks crediting one of the addresses in its wallet with the block reward. A miner can submit finished work to the client to help it solve it.

This solution is not ideal for most miners, as the use of pools as an intermediary between a client and a miner allow the block reward to be split between them.